# Android - How to make two Async calls in one Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have an activity which needs to make two remote server calls. The first is simple and happens when the page loads and I just make a call to fetch some data and show it...no problem.

The problem happens in the second call because once I call sendFeedback, it tries to execute the task, but the doInBackground() method was written for the original call, and thus the parameters won't work, and also the function that is called when the data is returned from the remote call won't be the same for both calls.

What is commonly done in a situation that I am facing where I need to make two different remote calls from one Activity?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just create a whole new Async task class?

Comment: Are they both running at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dymmeh suggests, just use two different `AsyncTask` subclasses.

Comment: @kabko thanks but how do I make two AsyncTask subclasses? I mean how do I call one class when needed, and not the other? :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion is. How did you make one AsyncTask subclass? Just do something similar for the second. Perhaps it would clear things up for all of us if you posted a little code or pseudo code of what you have so far to make things more concrete.

Comment: @kabko what I am not clear is whether I should have two declarations of this:     public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Comment: @kabko thats the start of the inner class the Async code.  And my remote call is made from sendFeedback with this call task.execute(params); which has nothing unique about it so how would the system know which of the two remote calls need to be made?

Comment: new class1.execute(); new class2.execute(); Good plan :P.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't quite follow what you want, but I think you're saying you want to make two asynchronous calls in sequence with the second depending on the first.

If my understanding is correct, start the second `AsyncTask` from the `onPostExecute()` method of the first.

Answer (score 2):

Just create 2 AsyncTask where you need them.

```
  new AsyncTask<String, Void, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // put task here

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    };
```